# Is it possible to enable user-level scope instead of a client-level scope in Spring Authorization Server? Is this a workable idea?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I'm currently using Spring Authorization Server. I've an oAuth client `aggregator` with `account profile openid` as allowed scopes. Every time a user uses the Authorization Code workflow, they are presented a consent page with these scopes (provided the request has scopes).

The `aggregator` client is used to generate tokens which will be used to initiate multiple financial transactions (for example). I'm looking at enabling a more fine-grained control.

Say, a user has accounts - `a`, `b` and `c`, but wants to authorize access only to `a` and `b`. I'm expecting the consent page to list these three accounts and accommodate these while generating the token, despite `a`, `b` and `c` not being a client-level `scope`.

I can build some service to fetch and paint these in the consent page. I am looking to see if I can extend Spring's existing consent functionality and extend it to scopes that are maintained outside the Authorization Server and not necessarily only client-level scopes.

I need some help in validating if my approach is correct and in understanding if Spring Authorization Server can help me achieve this through some customization.

I have been able to identify blocks of code in Spring Authorization Server, where the scope matching is done and checked if there is a hook given to override / disable this validation.

I am currently going through the design, documentation and the source code for Spring Authorization Server to see what bits I can re-use to build the custom user scopes and not rely on client-level scopes.